# Is there an efficient method to find all the self-inverse matrices with integers in a given range?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given $n$ and a range, for example $[-10,10]$, is there an efficient method to find
 all $n \times n$-matrices $A$ with integers in the given range, which are self-inverse (that means the equation $A=A^{-1}$ holds)?

Some necessary conditions for $A$:

- $\det(A)=-1$ or $\det(A)=1$
- $A$ has no eigenvalues other than $-1$ and $1$
- The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^2-1$

  With $A$, the matrices $-A$ , $A^T$ and $B^{-1}AB$ for any invertible matrix B
  are also self-inverse.

  So, is there a method to find the matrices systematically without checking
  all possible matrices, which would be infeasible for, lets say $n = 4$ and
  range $[-10,10]$?

Comment: See also my related question, if the only eigenvalues of a self-inverse matrix are -1 and 1.

Comment: Without loss of generality, we can assume $a_{11}\ge0$ and $a_{12}\ge a_{21}$ to reduce the number of matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have been studied much in the literature. The latest paper at MathSciNet was by Robert Hanson, titled "Self-Inverse Integer Matrices" (*College Mathematics Journal*, Vol 16, No 3 (Jun 1985), pp. 198-198). He proves that you can generate all self-inverse integer matrices by starting with a matrix of the form $\left[\begin{array}{c}I&A\\ 0&-I\end{array}\right]$ ($A$ is a rectangular matrix), and calculating $BAB^{-1}$, where $B$ ranges over all matrices you get from the identity matrix by doing the following row operations:

1. Swapping two rows
2. Adding a multiple of one row to another row
3. Multiplying all the entries in a row by -1

I'm not sure this helps much. *Maybe* you can limit the row operations once you know the matrix $A$.

Answer (score -4):

I think the number is infinite...
because all possible rotation angles (a) are possible (analogy with spin in Quantum mechanics) for n=2 we can write in general the matrix [cos(a), sin(a)](line 1) [sin(a), -cos(a)] (line 2)

Zeno Toffano (France)

Comment: the matrix you propose do not necessarily have *integer* coefficients (except for a finite number of $a$)

Comment: The number cannot be infinite because I have a finite range (with DISCRETE entries) and a finite matrix.